# Help Finding a Sci-Fi Book Title (Early 80s?)

Tags: story-identification

Don't know for sure but think this was a book as opposed to a short story...

Premise as far as I can remember:
Cold war between US and USSR had reached the point that prohibited conventional war, so the countries would do things like get the youth hooked on heroin or taint the water supply, etc.
The only other thing I can remember is that the book ended by the main character (I think he was a CIA operative) visiting a prostitute that turned out to be his daughter.
Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Because it's bound to be asked, my opinion is that this fits as science fiction as it's pretty obviously an alternate universe / history.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this isn't scifi. That's precisely what the CIA tried to do in real life.

Comment: What about this book made it SF? Contrary to the opinion of @FuzzyBoots, this sounds like Spy-Fi rather than Sci-Fi. In other words, the realm of James Bond and CSI: high tech gadgets, but other than that, not Science Fiction.

Comment: @SQB - Alternate universes, dystopian futures and alternate histories (in other words, speculative societies) are very much [on-topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35/are-questions-about-alternate-history-on-or-off-topic). That’s why we have a question about [tag:the-purge], for example.

Comment: I’m voting to reopen. From the description, it strongly sounds like this is an alternate history of the Cold War, even if similar techniques may actually have been employed in real life.

Comment: @SQB Spy-fi is not specifically off-topic, if a case can be made for the individual work. I think we should also take the asker's word for it that when they *said* it's a Sci-fi book, that it is such, even though they lack some strong SFF-nal elements in their description.

Comment: @CreationEdge yes, so I'm asking the OP to tell us what makes this SF. I *didn't* vote to close.

Comment: @SQB My first sentence there was what was meant for you, the rest general commentary on why I VTRO'd. Unfortunately unclear comment.

Comment: Maybe Frederick Pohl's [*The Cool War?*](https://www.amazon.com/Cool-War-Frederik-Pohl/dp/0345293835)

Comment: Reminds me a little of Ursula K. Le Guin's The Dispossessed, except in that the communist countries ended up on the moon and the earth was completely capitalist.

Comment: Looking through the replies, I feel that I should apologize. I'm afraid that I don't know all the different genres, and I read this about 35 yrs ago. I don't know if it would have been an alt-history because the Cold War was ongoing. I'm very sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @JoeL. Just read the synopsis of Pohl's book, and it sounds like the book I'm looking for. Publishing date fits perfectly, too. I'll let you know, and thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly Frederick Pohl's 1982 novel [*The Cool War.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345301374)

[image]

From a review on the Amazon link:

> Unitarian minister Reverend Hornswell "Horny" Hake is forced to join a
>   secret government cadre of dirty tricksters called "the Team" in this
>   wry, futuristic spoof of a spy novel. Hapless Hake's total
>   incompetence becomes apparent almost immediately when he is abducted
>   by the mysterious Leota, who works for an underground organization
>   dedicated to fighting the Team. This doesn't stop Hake from carrying
>   out his first assignment: escorting an unruly bunch of teenagers on a
>   tour of Europe in order to reduce worker productivity. This campaign
>   is typical of the "Cool War" Pohl envisions in which nations engage in
>   covert operations designed to make the opponent significantly less
>   competitive economically without the kind of national culpability that
>   might generate a military response. Hake finds himself well rewarded
>   for his pains, but is troubled by the moral implications of his
>   actions. In particular, he worries that the minor annoyances caused by
>   the Team are hurting innocent people more than their governments. The
>   intentional wastefulness of the Team goes against his long-ingrained
>   distaste for what this resource-starved society calls "piggery", and
>   in several subsequent encounters Leota asks him how he justifies his
>   part in activities that seem so morally abhorrent and at the same time
>   so politically meaningless. As Hake begins to act more independently,
>   he falls afoul of the Reddi brothers, a pair (literally) of
>   professional mercenaries who sometimes work with the Team, and other
>   times work against it. Will Hake make his final stand for the Team,
>   against the Team, or for himself?

Comment: I was able, with your help, to find a paperback edition. I'm sure from reading the synopsis that this is the book. Thank you so much!

Comment: @D.Doe: Glad to help! If it's the right book, please check it as "answered". It helps others who might be looking for the same book, and we get bragging points. ;)

Comment: I will do that. The book should be here in a few days.